# It is not possible to read txt files form folder in spark streaming mode

Tags: java, file, spark-streaming

I would like to read some text files from a folder and do some operation on them. I should mention that I am using intellij idea on Mac OS. Here's what I did during my tests:

1- I copied and paste files while my program ran

2- I moved them from another folder

3- I renamed them

4- I put in new files for each tests

5- I tested with both Scala and Java

Although I did the test with above conditions each time, nothing could be read from the folder. I put my java code here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String outputPathPrefix;
        String inputFolder;

        inputFolder ="/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/SparkStreamingWordCountFolder/inputfolder";
        outputPathPrefix = "/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/SparkStreamingWordCountFolder/output/";

        // Create a configuration object and set the name of the application
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("Spark Streaming word count");

        // Create a Spark Streaming Context object
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(10));

        // Create a DStream reading the content of the input folder
        JavaDStream<String> lines = jssc.textFileStream(inputFolder);

        // Apply the "standard" trasformations to perform the word count task
        // However, the "returned" RDDs are DStream/PairDStream RDDs
        JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new Split());

        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordsOnes = words.mapToPair(new WordOne());

        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordsCounts = wordsOnes.reduceByKey(new Sum());

        wordsCounts.print();

        wordsCounts.dstream().saveAsTextFiles(outputPathPrefix, "");

        // Start the computation
        jssc.start();

        jssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(120000);

        jssc.close();

    }
```

Can you help me to find the problem? Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you try the minimal standalone project I provided to you? https://gist.github.com/maasg/54d6da2d9e27edf5913c1b7946af2e79

Comment: @maasg: Thanks for your answer. Yes I have done that and it did't work! I think it does not work on Mac. :(